# How to replace hidden elements in access?

Tags: microsoft-access, query, microsoft-access-2007, report

I work with MS-Access database with a lot of tables, qureys and reports.

It is easy to hidden some elements (by right mouse click then hidden options), but I do not fin the option to replace those hidden elements.

Where I can find this option?

I use MS office 2007 on windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on the "All Access Objects" on the Navigation pane, select navigation options, at the bottom there is a show hidden objects selection button.[image: screen shot]